# File Helper library to resolve problem of CSV file with field having comma values in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, read.csv, filehelpers

I am using File Helper library in my .net core project to Parse CSV file to a class and i am getting error while doing so because one the field in the file have comma seperated value so i am unable parse it.

Here is the value in the file

```
**Branch,ANumber,Type,PNumber,CustNumber,Reference,MemberName,Code,IncidentDate
XYZ,15555,New,4545454545,8998-42454-1215,S454545/112,"Newmon, Osborn",GGG SHF,28/01/2022**
```

here the field value Newmon, Osborn is the trouble

```
 var filePath = @"File.csv";
    List<string> lines = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath));
    var data = testSubject.Parse(lines).FirstOrDefault();
    Assert.Equal("XYZ",data.Branch);
    Assert.Equal("15555",data .ANumber);
    Assert.Equal("New",data.Type);
    Assert.Equal("4545454545",data.PNumber);
    Assert.Equal("899-42-12154",data.CustNumber);
    Assert.Equal("S454545/112",data.Reference);
    Assert.Equal("Newmon, Osborn",data.MemberName);
    Assert.Equal("GGG SHF",data.Code);
    Assert.Equal(DateTime.ParseExact("28/01/2022", "dd/MM/yyyy", null),data.IncidentDate);
```

Here is my class

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines]
public class ABC
{
    [FieldNullValue(typeof(string), "")]
    public string Branch{ get; set; }
    [FieldNullValue(typeof(string), "")]
    public string ANumber{ get; set; }
    [FieldNullValue(typeof(string), "")]
    public string Type{ get; set; }
    [FieldNullValue(typeof(string), "")]
    public string PNumber{ get; set; }
    [FieldNullValue(typeof(string), "")]
    public string CustNumber{ get; set; }
    [FieldNullValue(typeof(string), "")]
    public string Reference{ get; set; }
    [FieldNullValue(typeof(string), "")]
    public string MemberName{ get; set; }
    [FieldNullValue(typeof(string), "")]
    public string Code{ get; set; }
    [FieldNullValue(typeof(DateTime), "1900-01-01"), FieldConverter(ConverterKind.DateMultiFormat, "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd", "MM/dd/yyyy")]
    public DateTime IncidentDate{ get; set; }
    }
```

While validating the values with the parsing engine with following code i am getting the error

```
ParsingEngine.ReadStringAsList(line);
```

Can anybody help me in this situation. thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `[FieldQuoted]` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

The library you're referring to is probably [FileHelpers.net](https://www.filehelpers.net/) instead of 'File Helper'.
At first glance it doesn't seem to be able to work with text-qualified CSV fields. Maybe you could use the [Multiple Delimiters](https://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultipleDelimiters/) option to split on quote first, then comma?

Otherwise you'll need a more sophisticated CSV library like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) or [my own library](https://github.com/simmetric/Simmetric.IO.Csv)

Comment: It works fine with text-qualified CSV fields.